# What is the procedure for Shudras to do tharpanam?

Tags: shudra, eclipse, shraddha

Namaskaram, I tried searching online for the procedures for a shudra to do tharpanam and I wasn't able to find it. Since we do not wear yajnopavitam, what is the procedure to do tharpanam.

Dhanyosmi.

Comment: On Youtube you should look for PVR Narasimha Rao's easy Tarpana procedure video .. according to him, the procedure can be followed by anybody irrespective of caste etc.

Comment: Dharmasastras 
like the Vaidyanatha-Diksitiyam describe how members of the fourth varna (though they dont wear the sacred thread)  
have the marriage samskara , along with it aupasana,jatakarma and namakarana ceremonies.It also details sraddha ceremony and apara-
karma (obsequies)rituals . They are dealt  in the chapters on varnasrama, anhika 
and sraddha in the Vaidyanatha-Diksitiyam. Only a practicing vedic officiator can give the right guidance.

Comment: Many have forsaken wearing yajnopavitam over time . It may not be true that those who do not wear yajnopavitam are sudras.

Comment: @Athrey all texts unanimously agree that upanayana samskara is necessary in order to be classified as dvija. Even kids born to brahmin families are considered as Shudras before their upanayana . The claim of  certain groups in North India to  Kshatriya & Vaishya status without undergoing upanayana is scripturally illegitimate & null-n-void.

Comment: @AnubrataBit, Quite true, in view of 'Janmana Jayate...'  yajnopavitam is a prequisite to perform  samskaaras , (except for fourth varna)..
But the intent of my comment is , since  some varnas  have forsaken wearing yajnopavitam though entitled, does it mean they should follow the samskaara(procedure)meant for fourth varna , bcos procedure for same samskaara is stated  differently for different varna.(Probably a Vedic officiator can  give OP the right guidance.)

Comment: Raghunandana says in the Smrititattva that women & shudras should perform Vaidika rites according to the Grihyasutras that follow the Yajurveda but they themselves shouldn't recite Vaidika mantras & make the priest recite mantras on their behalf.

Comment: @AnubrataBit , Thanks for the reference.